# React-Native : How to trigger set of buttons while keep pressing

Tags: button, react-native

By using a component [Button from NativeBase](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-def-headref), I know there are two events which are `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` which are working fine on one button, but if I keep pressing on a button and drag to another button, the other button is not triggered. Is there any event for that? Or any other idea?

(I am working on a Calendar and each day cell is a button, I would like to hold the press on a day, and when I release the press on another day, the other day button trigger)

Comment: IIRC there's a lock whenever you click on a button which doesn't allow you to click another button while it's still pressed. I could be wrong.

Comment: it seems so that there is lock and i couldn't find any other way around that